# Firefox DevTools: Console & Network panel broken with "ReferenceError: IntersectionObserver is not defined"

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In a normal firefox from "release" software channel, I have this error in the network panel:

[image: error in network panel]

This error is only shown in network panel. The console panel is just completely blank .

The other panels (inspector, debugger, style editor...) are all working fine.

Installed addons:

- cookie quick manager
- web developer ([see addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/))

I have another profile running which works fine! (=> so I guess it's not the firefox installation)

My guess would be that one of the addons causes problems, but error stays even in "Troubleshoot mode" (with all addons disabled)

Web searches for this specific error message all point to concrete problems with react, nothing that I could make sense of for my problem.

Anybody seen this? What can I do to investigate/test further?

Comment: I have set up a new profile now, and all panels are functioning correctly. My guess is that the Web Developer addon is causing problems. And I see that it was last updated in Jan 2020. Is anybody aware that this addons causes problems for newer FF versions?

Comment: This is obviously a bug in the DevTools related to your profile settings. I suggest to report this bug to Mozilla. This can be done via the "File Bug Report" button shown within your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianZartner. I do tweak my FF profiles a lot (e.g. user.js from ghacks.net). But all my other FF installations and profiles work fine - with very similar settings. Alright, if it is not too much of a hassle I will file this to mozilla.